# rolling 7 among 3 rolls dice probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to figure out the probability of rolling a 7 with two dice, over 3 rolls.

Is it P=(18/36), or P=(6/36)x(6/36)x(6/36), or just P=(3/36), or something else entirely?

I'm so confused.

Comment: For clarification, you are rolling two dice, computing the sum of their digits and asking if it is a seven or not, and then repeating this process until you have asked this question a total of three times?  Are you curious about the sum being seven exactly once? at least once? all three times?  Or perhaps you are rolling three dice, and asking if some two of the three dice add to seven?

Comment: Thanks for asking this clarifying question. I'm trying to figure out the probability of the sum being 7 AT LEAST once, over 3 rolls.

Comment: Then my answer below is still valid.  $\frac{18}{36}$ would be an appropriate answer for "WITP that in the first roll the first die is a one or a two or a three", $(\frac{6}{36})^3$ is an appropriate answer for "WITP you roll a sum of seven *all three times*", and $\frac{3}{36}$ is an appropriate answer for "WITP you rolled a sum of seven on the first throw and on the second throw you rolled an even number"

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are rolling two dice, computing their sum, and then asking the question of if the sum is equal to 7, and then repeating this process.

The **only** time you add probabilities is if the events are mutually exclusive (no overlap).

Let $E_1$ be the event that the first pair of dice add to seven, $E_2$ be the event that the second pair of dice add to seven, and $E_3$ be the event that the third pair of dice add to seven.

If we are curious about "What is the probability that in three attempts, *at least one of the times* we get a sum of seven", then we are asking the question $Pr(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3)$.  In the case that they were mutually exclusive, then yes $Pr(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3) = Pr(E_1) + Pr(E_2) + Pr(E_3)$, however that is **not** the case here (it is possible that you roll a total of seven in the first attempt and also in the second attempt), so we do not add.

The ideal way to proceed is via inclusion-exclusion (in its simplest form) which says $Pr(F) = 1 - Pr(F^c)$ (here I use $^c$ to denote complement, i.e. the opposite event).  So, $Pr(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3) = 1 - Pr(E_1^c\cap E_2^c\cap E_3^c)$  (where $E_i^c$ is the event of *not* rolling a sum of 7 on the $i^{th}$ attempt).

As we are dealing with rolling dice, we are tacitly assuming each roll to be independent of one another, so it is $=1 - Pr(E_1^c)\cdot Pr(E_2^2)\cdot Pr(E_3^c)$.

Worded in plainer English, the probability that you roll a sum of seven at least once is opposite the probability that you roll a sum of seven none of the times.

Complete the problem by solving for $Pr(E_i), Pr(E_i^c),$ and $1 - Pr(E_1^c)\cdot Pr(E_2^2)\cdot Pr(E_3^c)$